# WoocommerceNet : product.updaterange() take a long time and doesn't end

Tags: c#, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm using WooCommercenet to synchronize a batch of items to the WooCommerce shop, from a windows service as follows:

```
MyRestAPI rest = new MyRestAPI($"{WooUrl}/wp-json/wc/v3/", key, secret);
var wc = new WCObject(rest);

....
BatchObject<Product> pb2 = new BatchObject<Product>();
pb2.create = products.Values.ToList();
Log.Info("start update woocommerce");
var result = await wc.Product.UpdateRange(pb2);
Log.Info("endupdate woocommerce");
```

But I'm getting trouble as the update doesn't finish and take a very long time.

How to resolve this issue?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i figure out the issue after hard days. By calling .Result, i was  blocking the main thread, which could result in a deadlock.

i removed the .Result from the calling method that calls the mehotd above as follows:

```
private void parentmethod(){
    ....
    ...
   var result = updateRange2(dict);
    ...
   }




private List<string> updateRange2(){
     ....
     BatchObject<Product> pb2 = new BatchObject<Product>();
     pb2.create = products.Values.ToList();
     Log.Info("start update woocommerce");
     var result = await wc.Product.UpdateRange(pb2).Result;
     Log.Info("endupdate woocommerce");
     ....
   }
```